# PhpMyAdmin freezes by creating triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I try to create a trigger from the SQL console of PhpMyAdmin but the navigator loads infinitely

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_history BEFORE INSERT
ON history FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO newsfeed(user_ID, date_action, action, pg_ID, rk_ID, vote) 
VALUES (NEW.user_ID, NOW(), "vote", NEW.page_ID, NEW.ranking_ID, SELECT IF(NEW.liked='1','1','-1') AS vote );
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

After a certain time I have this error : Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries\import\sql.php on line 259

Maybe it's a delimiter issue, yet I choosed ";" in the delimiter field on the bottom of console.

Answer (score 0):

`delimiter` is a MySQL client command, not SQL. I believe you need to choose `|` as your delimiter from the drop-down box on PHPMyAdmin's SQL tab, then use the same code you posted here without the `delimiter` commands.

I just tried a simple statement within `delimiter` commands, and although the first `delimiter` command didn't seem to do much, the second one causes it to hang. Removing it solved it in my case.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_history BEFORE INSERT
ON history FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO newsfeed(user_ID, date_action, action, pg_ID, rk_ID, vote) 
VALUES (NEW.user_ID, NOW(), "vote", NEW.page_ID, NEW.ranking_ID, SELECT IF(NEW.liked='1','1','-1') AS vote );
END |
```